# Automatic comments to redmine after teamcity build

Tags: teamcity, redmine

I want to make automatic comment in redmine issue after build in teamcity. For example teamcity made build for branch , I want to make comment in redmine about build result in issue/xyz. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a new build step at the end that will run some sort of script or program that you'll need to make.

What the script will do is make use of the TeamCity REST API to get the changes. ([See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460177/971423))

Then you can use the [Redmine REST API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api) to update the issue based off the changes found using the TeamCity REST API.

Comment: @corvax I'd be interested to see your script if you wrote one